# Multi markers on Google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, styling

Hello nice people of SO,

I am looking for a little guidance in relation to Google maps..
I am looking to set different styled markers on Google maps. The styles I want will be influenced from variables help in a database, ie Hotel, Cafe, Bed'n'breakfast.

I would like to alter the icons depending on these values.
I have changed the stock icons with little issues, but to change them depending on the values from the DB is an issue.

I have values passed  from the DB in a diff file and can show them on the map. For instance I am using point.hotelComments to gather hotel comments.. All are showing up OK so my connection and printing is fine. I have the amenity I want to influence the change stored in the DB user "Type" Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated!

The code I am using to date to print onto the map is:

```
<div id="map-container" class="col-md-12"></div>
```

```
            <script>
                var markers = [];
                var map;

                  function initialize()
                   {

                        var mapOptions = 
                        {
                          center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.273224, -9.051864),
                          zoom: 15
                        };

                        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-container"),mapOptions);

                        $.ajax
                        ({
                            type: "GET",
                            dataType: "json",
                            url: "http://localhost/Project/mapdata2.php",
                            success: function (data) 
                            {
                                $.each(data,function(index,point)
                                {
                                    createMarker(point.Lat, point.Lng, map, point.hotelName, point.type, point );
                                });

                            }   
                        });
                    }
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


            function createMarker(Lat, Lng, map, title, Type, point)
                {
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Lng);
                var iconBase = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/';
                //http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/coffeehouse.png
                //http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/coffeehouse.shadow.png
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
                    {
                        position: latlng,
                        map: map,
                        title: title,
                        type: Type,
                        icon: iconBase + 'coffeehouse.png'

                        //icon: iconBase + 'icon_' + Type + '.png' 
                    });

                marker.setMap(map);

                markers.push(marker);



                //Adds content 
                      var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
                          '<div id="siteNotice">'+
                          '</div>'+
                          '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="leadBigBlue"> ' + point.hotelName +' </h1>'+   point.fullAddress +
                          '<div id="bodyContent">'+
                          '<p><b>' + point.hotelName + '</b>, ' +  point.hotelComments +  '  </p> ' +
                          '<p><b> Language 1 </b>   ' +  point.hotelLang +  ' </p>'+
                          '<p><b> Language 2</b>   ' +  point.hotelLang2 +  ' </p>'+
                          '<p><b> Cultures </b>   ' +  point.Cult +  ' </p>'+
                          '<p><b>Website</b> <a href="  ' +  point.localWeblink +  ' ">'+
                          'Press Here</a> </p>'+

                          '</div>'+
                          '</div>';

                      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                          content: contentString
                      });

                      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                        infowindow.open(map,marker);
                      });
                }


    </script>
```

Comment: What is not working? I'd do it that way. No real need for the switch as in the below answer, if your different variables put together make the name of your icons...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For your unique styling issue:**

We do something like this....See if you can follow along and implement.

...and if you have a question left me know because some things are happen outside of this script (the data stuff).

```
google.load('maps', '3', {
other_params: 'sensor=false'
});

google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);

var markerClusterer = null;
var map = null;
var imageUrl = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=mm&chs=24x32&' +
'chco=FFFFFF,008CFF,000000&ext=.png';

    function initialize() {
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(41.45,-98.87);

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 3,
    center: center,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var markers = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.count; i++) {
    spinnerUp(i);
    }

        function spinnerUp() {

            var data_mapper = data.locationstuff[i];

            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data_mapper.latitude,data_mapper.longitude);

            var boxText = "<div style='border: 1px solid black; margin-top: 8px; background: yellow; padding: 5px;'>";
                boxText += data_mapper.title + "<br>" + data_mapper.address + "<br>" + data_mapper.city + ", " + data_mapper.zip;
                boxText += "</div>";

            switch (data_mapper.iconSpecial)
                {
                case 0:
                  var iconColorSpecial = "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/red-dot.png";
                  break;
                case 1:
                  var iconColorSpecial = "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png";
                  break;
                }

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: latLng,icon:iconColorSpecial});

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                                                    content: boxText
                                                    ,disableAutoPan: false
                                                    ,maxWidth: 0
                                                    ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, 0)            
                                                    ,zIndex: null
                                                    <!---,boxStyle: { 
                                                    background: "url('http://www.garylittle.ca/map/artwork/tipbox.gif') no-repeat"
                                                    ,opacity: 0.75
                                                    ,width: "280px"
                                                    }--->
                                                    ,closeBoxMargin: "10px 2px 2px 2px"
                                                    ,closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif"
                                                    ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
                                                    ,isHidden: false
                                                    ,pane: "floatPane"
                                                    ,enableEventPropagation: false});

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {infowindow.open(map, this);});
        markers.push(marker);       
        }

        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
    }
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: WOW Frank, thanks for the fast reply and the abundance of code.. 

I will gladly have a look through that and see if I can find a solution. Thanks again

Comment: You are welcome...Google maps can be fun/impressive with stuff like this. :)

Comment: For sure it can. Ia m just learning it.. which is even more fun.. Thanks again for that.. Sorry I cannot vote your answer up - I am still new here... **But have a virtual vote up**